# unity, не работает FindAll в списке объектов класса созданного в GameManager

Tags: c#, unity3d

В гейменеджере объявлен класс и создан и заполнен из БД список его объектов:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Random = UnityEngine.Random;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{   
    public class PlantClass
    {
        public int plantId;
        public string plantName;
        public int plantFruitId;
    }

    public List<PlantClass> allPlants= new List<PlantClass>();

...

}
```

В скрипте прикрепленном к префабу пытаюсь найти объект, подходящий по условию:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Ground : MonoBehaviour
{
    GameObject GM;

    void Start()
    {
        GM = GameObject.Find("GameManager");
    }

    void Update()
    {
         List<GameManager.PlantClass> getAllPlants = GM.GetComponent<GameManager>().allPlants;
         List<GameManager.PlantClass> neededPlants = getAllPlants.FindAll(getAllPlants => getAllPlants.plantId == 2)
    }
}
```

и получаю ошибку error CS0136: A local or parameter named 'getAllPlants' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter.
Подскажите, в какую сторону копать?

Comment: поменял (не совсем понятно, разве я не передаю getAllPlants в качестве входных параметров слева от лямбда-оператора?), теперь получаю ошибку:
error CS1061: 'List<GameManager.PlantClass>' does not contain a definition for 'plantId' and no accessible extension method 'plantId' accepting a first argument of type 'List<GameManager.PlantClass>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Действительно! Спасибо за науку. Не сразу, правда, сообразил, что при изменении имени переменной слева от лямбда-оператора нужно на нее же заменить и справа в предикате.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы внутри лямбды объявили переменную, с таким же именем как и в теле класса, и теперь выражение внутри лямбды неоднозначно.

```
getAllPlants.FindAll(getAllPlants => getAllPlants.plantId == 2);
```

Для того чтобы Все было корректно аргумент, к которому Вы обращаетесь и который передаете должен иметь уникальное имя, вот так, например:

```
getAllPlants.FindAll(plant => plant .plantId == 2);
```